# How number of rows examined is greater than number of rows in table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for auditing. I used this query for getting no of users currently logged in. But , This query takes so long time on last couple of days. On analysed from slow query log the number of rows examined is too long.

Total rows on the table for that day is `6032194` (

```
    select count(*) from audit where audit.created_time 
    between  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 3 DAY) * 1000
  AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 2 day) * 1000
```

).

**Query**

```
    select count(user_id) from audit where audit.created_time 
between  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 3 DAY) * 1000  AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 2 day) * 1000 
and operation in ('s','g','y','fb');
```

**Explain Output**

```
         id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: audit
         type: range
possible_keys: IAMAccountAudit_CTndx
          key: IAMAccountAudit_CTndx
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 16434866
        Extra: Using where
```

It's executing as range query. But it examines `86158436` rows.

Slow Query Log:

```
    # Time: 130216  1:09:21
# User@Host: root[root] @  [bharathik]
# Query_time: 1853.751416  Lock_time: 0.000101 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 86158436
SET timestamp=1361005761;
    SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 1 DAY) * 1000, 'SIGNIN', 0, count(distinct(zuid)) as SIGN_IN_COUNT from audit where  audit.CREATED_TIME BETWEEN 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()  - INTERVAL 3 DAY) * 1000  AND 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()-INTERVAL 2 day) * 1000
```

**Create Table**

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| auto_id               | bigint(19)   | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| user_id               | varchar(100) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| service               | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name                  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| operation             | varchar(15)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ipaddress             | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| referrer              | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| user_agent            | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_time          | bigint(19)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the key IAMAccountAudit_CTndx is an index on the created_time field, correct?  Also, you say you're looking for the number of users currently logged in, but your query appears to be counting the total number of rows over the period of a day that match "operation in ('s','g','y','fb')"

Comment: It might be helpful to post a create table and an insert statement to generate some sample data to try the query on.  (Obviously not your whole table, but a few rows so we can see the structure and try the queries on actual data.)

Comment: You present three different statements and ask why you get different number of rows examined/returned?

Comment: @Nathan , I added my table details.

Answer (score 0):

Since the 2nd SQL query has an IN clause, additional 'rows' need to be evaluated. These additional 'rows' represent the temporary results from the IN clause.